# Do any laptops exist with multiple power connectors?

Tags: laptop, power-supply

Are any laptops available with multiple places a power cable could be plugged-in?

It would be very handy to have a connector on either side of the machine, and not just one (for when the available outlet is on the other side from where the connector on the laptop is).

Comment: As an aside, why on earth do they give us such short power cables for towers and laptops nowadays?  Back in the desktop computer days, when the computer was close to the outlet, 10' cords were the norm.  Now, with towers tucked away far from outlets and laptops that we like to move around on the desk, we get stuck with 6' cords!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of late 2018, at least Acer Chromebooks that power over USB-C ([like this one](https://us-store.acer.com/laptops/chromebook/acer-spin-15-laptop-cp315-1h-p1k8)) can be powered from either side

Answer (score 2):

Good question. I have however never seen such a laptop. I believe it is unlikely there is one, because in laptops space is scarce, and if there is free space for connectors, manufacturers would probably rather add an extra connector that would otherwise be missing, rather than a redundant power connector.

That said, I have face the same problem. A simple solution would be a longer power cable.